# illegal start of simple pattern about for expression in scala

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

```
object main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for (
      i <- 1 to 10
      if i % 2 == 0;
      j <- 2 to 8
      if j % 2 == 1;
      ) {
      println(s"i: ${i}, j: ${j}")
      val t = i + j
      println(s"t: ${t}")
    }
  }
}
```

Compiler complains: `illegal start of simple pattern.`

If I remove the second semicolon:

```
object main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for (
      i <- 1 to 10
      if i % 2 == 0;
      j <- 2 to 8
      if j % 2 == 1
      ) {
      println(s"i: ${i}, j: ${j}")
      val t = i + j
      println(s"t: ${t}")
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine.

How to explain this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for` comprehension can be defined using `()` or `{}`. Separator in case of `()` is `;` and in case of `{}` is `new line`.

You are mixing both of them.

Try below (uses `{}` and `new line` separator):

```
object main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for {
      i <- 1 to 10
      if i % 2 == 0
      j <- 2 to 8
      if j % 2 == 1
    } {
      println(s"i: ${i}, j: ${j}")
      val t = i + j
      println(s"t: ${t}")
    }
  }
}
```

Below one uses `()` and `;` separator:

```
object main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for (i <- 1 to 10 if i % 2 == 0; j <- 2 to 8 if j % 2 == 1) {
      println(s"i: ${i}, j: ${j}")
      val t = i + j
      println(s"t: ${t}")
    }
  }
}
```